# Modelling a real-life diode

Tags: diodes, power-electronics, simulation, multisim, simulink

I have a final year project for electrical engineering. My part of the project is to design a rectifier that receives an AC voltage from an antenna and provides a power management unit with rectified DC voltage.

I have a base design and simulation for my rectifier, however, it's based on ideal diodes.

I found real diodes that would be applicable for my application. I want to simulate my design with the real diodes for which I have a datasheet. I want to see the effect of the real diodes on my output voltage and try to work around the losses.

The problem is: how can I model these real-life diodes in a simulator based on their data sheet? My instructor suggested using ADS, but I have no experience with it and it's anything but user friendly.

I have experience with Multisim and Simulink. But from my research, I didn't find a way to use the properties of diodes (Cj, Is, Rs, etc.) to model these real-life diodes.

Is there a way to model these diodes in Simulink or Multisim, and if not, is there any user friendly application that can do this?

I'm only simulating my rectifier, without anything connected to it.

Comment: What frequency is your rectifier operating at? What models do you have access to for your real diodes?

Comment: Its HF application, f=2GHz, HSMS-2852 from Avago Technologies.

Comment: Define sensitivity , impedance and capacitance which varies with size and noise figure.

Comment: Here is a thread with a similar diode from Avago simulated in ADS: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/416261/ads-simulation-why-doesnt-the-diode-rectify-the-signal

Answer (score 2):

There are SPICE model parameters available from [here](https://www.rcscomponents.kiev.ua/datasheets/avago-hsms-2852-blkg-datasheet.pdf)

[image]

Since you're operating at a relatively high frequency you should also model the [package](http://www.hp.woodshot.com/hprfhelp/4_downld/lit/diodelit/an1124.pdf):

You can stick that package lumped model and SPICE diode parameters into any SPICE program such as LTspice (free download), however you would need something like ADS to adequately model any sort of connections and such like that are not much smaller than the wavelength of your signal, in other words much bigger than 5 or 10mm.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong. you're basically saying that, LTspice can model such diode, however, I would need ADS for a more accurate modeling of the whole rectifier circuit.
Any suggestions/advice on ADS on how to utilize it ??

Comment: I'm saying if you want to model some tiny diodes connected together in a small space with a feed from a transmission line and DC out, then LTspice can do it. As far as ADS goes, search for a tutorial such as [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=04BfajzXnmM) one. Note that Avago I think is now Broadcom and ADS is now owned by Keysight. All these were originally Hewlett-Packard.